# Copy and paste text in virtual terminal

Tags: command-line, copy, paste

How do you copy and paste text in a non-GUI terminal?

E.g. if I login on an Ubuntu server and type 'test' at the command line (I assume that's a virtual terminal) how do I then copy / paste that? E.g.

```
$ test
```

Note, I **haven't** booted into a GUI environment as yet.

If it helps, I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.01 LTS.

Comment: No, that's between TTYs. I would just like to get it working initially in a single one.

Answer (score 4):

press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to go to the start of the line

press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> to cut ("kill") the text from the cursor to the end of the line

to paste ("yank"), press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd>

Comment: Note, that cutting from any other point till end ofbline is fine too, one doesn't have to navigate to the beginning of the line

Comment: Note that this is not the functionality of the terminal. The kill ring is implemented in bash and it stays in the single instance of it. If you run a different application (even just a new instance of bash) you cannot "yank" the content of the original kill ring.